# Laravel Livewire gives blank iframe when attempt to update record

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I am using bootstrap models to add and update data. When there is no change in data while updating, livewire works fine. But it gives a blank black iframe screen when I try to update data.

Here is my code update code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\Category as ModelsCategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

#[Title('Manage Categories')]
class Category extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $categories = [], $name, $description, $image, $categoryId;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:categories,name', 'max:50'],
        'description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:5000'],
        'image' => ['required', 'image', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,webp', 'max:1024'],
    ];

    protected function get(): Collection
    {
        return ModelsCategory::with('media')->orderByDesc('id')->get(['id', 'name', 'description']);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->categories = $this->get();
        return view('livewire.admin.category', ['categories' => $this->categories]);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate();
        $category = ModelsCategory::create($validated);
        $category->addMedia($this->image)->toMediaCollection('images');
        $this->dispatch('closeAddModel');
        session()->flash('success', 'Category has been added');
    }

    public function edit(ModelsCategory $category)
    {
        $this->categoryId = $category->id;
        $this->name = $category->name;
        $this->description = $category->description;

        $this->dispatch('openEditModel');
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:categories,name,' . $this->categoryId, 'max:50'],
            'description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:5000'],
        ]);

        $category = ModelsCategory::where('id', $this->categoryId)->first();
        $category->update([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
        ]);
        if ($this->image) {
            $category->clearMediaCollection('images');
            $category->addMedia($this->image)->toMediaCollection('images');
        }

        $this->reset();

        $this->dispatch('closeEditModel');

        session()->flash('success', 'Category has been updated');
    }
}
```

I have used multiple methods like mass assignment. $fillable is also added. In some methods, I don't get any error but it does not update the record.

Answer (score 0):

In update method, I changed

```
 $category = ModelsCategory::where('id', $this->categoryId)->first();
```

to

```
 $category = ModelsCategory::where('id', $this->category->id)->update($validated);
```

Don't know why but chaining update method worked.

Comment: Does the first line work if you do `$this->category->id` there too? Chances are it's `$this->category_id`, not `$this->categoryId` in the model.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah I tried but it didn't help. When I chained update method, it worked

Comment: My guess would be you've got multiple rows matching your `where`; the `first()` will mean you act on only one of them, the `update()` will work on all of them.